# Getting text between tags which have attributes in php

Tags: php, regex

preg_match_all returning the false when  I am trying to get the text between the tags which have attributes.

```
$str ="<h1 class="page-title" id="page-title-heading" aria-labelledby="page-title-heading toolbar-amount" > <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" >Sarees</span> </h1>";
$king = preg_match('/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/s', $str, $matches);
if ($king) {
echo $matches[0];
}else{
echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "anything but `>`" to take into account possible attributes:

```
$king = preg_match('/<h1[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h1>/s', $str, $matches);
                        ^^^^^
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/PJ4OqU

Comment: Thanks for the help..but I made changes to my question..your code works for previous one...but not for this one...

Comment: it's working for that...but the problem lies here...I have a task to get the content from a website...whenever I am trying the above String it's working..but when I am trying for that website it's returning false...

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars()` function since it converts special characters like `<` to their corresponding HTML entity `&lt;` then a regex can't match on `<`. @ShaikSalam